# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.durgasoft.config.BeansConfig

Tags: java, spring

Can you guys help me on this. I am new to Spring. I am using spring 4.1.6.release.
I am using JDK 21. It is working fine with xml configurations. I have tried changing JDK to JDK8 but still it was not  working.

[Project Structure jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyytB.jpg)

HelloBeans_JavaConfig.Java

```
package com.durgasoft.beans;
public class HelloBeans_JavaConfig {
static {
System.out.println("Bean Loading.....");
}
public HelloBeans_JavaConfig() {
System.out.println("Bean Created....");
}
public String sayHello() {
    return "Hello User";
    }
    }
```

BeansConfig.java

```
package com.durgasoft.config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.durgasoft.beans.HelloBeans_JavaConfig;

@Configuration
public class BeansConfig {
    
@Bean
public HelloBeans_JavaConfig helloBean() 
{
return new HelloBeans_JavaConfig();
}
}
```

Test.java

```
package com.durgasoft.test;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import com.durgasoft.beans.HelloBeans_JavaConfig;
import com.durgasoft.config.BeansConfig;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BeansConfig.class);
    HelloBeans_JavaConfig bean = (HelloBeans_JavaConfig)context.getBean(HelloBeans_JavaConfig.class);
    System.out.println(bean.sayHello());    
}
}
```

While running the application, Application's throwing this exception.
Exception:-

```
Mar 22, 2024 4:28:00 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5d6f64b1: startup date [Fri Mar 22 16:28:00 IST 2024]; root of context hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.durgasoft.config.BeansConfig
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:395)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75bOJ.jpg)
```